# Use a multimap query parameters as one parameter in Retrofit android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a retrofit request in the form of

`https://my_base_url/customer_id/file_name?query1=value1&query2=value2&query3=value3&query4=value4`

so i declare the request in my interface as

```
@GET("{customer_id}/{file_name}")
    @Streaming
    suspend fun getFilePart(
        @Path(value = "customer_id") customerId: Int,
        @Path(value = "file_name") filename: String,
        @QueryMap queryMap: Map<String, String>
    ): ResponseBody
```

However, due to the Api of my app, what i have from the querMap, is the whole String as one parameter, and the keys of the queryMap are different every time. So what i want is a way to pass the whole queryMap as one String. Something like that below

```
    @GET("{customer_id}/{file_name}?${wholeQueryAsaString}")
    @Streaming
    suspend fun getFilePart(
        @Path(value = "customer_id") customerId: Int,
        @Path(value = "file_name") filename: String,
        wholeQueryAsaString: String
    ): ResponseBody
```

where the ***wholeQueryAsaString*** has the value
***query1=value1&query2=value2&query3=value3&query4=value4***

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 val queryMap: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        map["value1"] = query1
        map["value2"] = query2
        map["value3"] = query3

@GET("{customer_id}/{file_name}")
    @Streaming
    suspend fun getFilePart(
        @Path(value = "customer_id") customerId: Int,
        @Path(value = "file_name") filename: String,
        @FieldMap queryMap: HashMap<String, String>
    ): ResponseBody
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, i have edited the question because it was not very clear what i wanted!